# How can I use mysql as jupyterhub's database?

Tags: mysql, docker, jupyterhub

The default database for JupyterHub is a SQLite database. But I want to replace SQLite database with MySQL. I tried with the config variable in the config file.

```
c.JupyterHub.db_url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test'
```

But when I run jupyterhub then it yields the error as :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test'
```

I searched and researched the official docs of jupyterhub but didn't find any thing related to my issue. Any solution to this problem?? Anyone ???

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Found the exact line that solve the above problem.

```
c.JupyterHub.db_url = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://{}:{}@{}/{}{}'.format("username","password","host","database","")
```

Answer (score 1):

Its an addition to the correct answer above if you dont add that arguement when using mysql you will have timeout issues, as mentioned as per documentation (https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/database.html)

Answer (score 0):

[RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) says that url syntax has to be defined as follows:

```
//<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<url-path>
```

RFC1738 is not the same syntax than [JDBC specification](https://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index2.html). It looks like you're trying to parse a RFC1738-url (needed by JupyterHub) with JDBC syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Make you also add the option for pool recycling in your JH config.  As per documentation.

```
c.JupyterHub.db_kwargs = {"pool_recycle":300}
```

Comment: That, doesn't look to be solving the problem statement here.